# How to execute root project first before all subprojects in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to execute root project first before all the subprojects and the reason is I have a set of tasks in root project which generates properties by appending to properties.gradle or local.properties file (ex : VAR=10) which then I want to use it in all the subprojects.

Since gradle build runs in parallel when I try to refer the properties in subprojects which will be fail.

Expecting a reply thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should read about the basic concept of Projects and Tasks in Gradle (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:projects_and_tasks)  :  you don't  "execute a project", you execute Tasks. in your case, you should use the concept of Tasks Dependencies , to make sure that tasks defined in your root project are always executed before tasks from subprojects (using `task.dependsOn()` API for example)

Comment: I had mentioned in the subject "I have set of tasks in root project" when I say execute root project obviously tasks in the project.

Comment: I have used task.dependsOn()  still subprojects task executes and failes to obtain the properties

Comment: allprojects {  
  afterEvaluate {  
    for(def task in it.tasks)  
      if((task != rootProject.tasks.task1) && (task != rootProject.tasks.task2) && (task != rootProject.tasks.task3) && (task != rootProject.tasks.task4))
        task.dependsOn rootProject.tasks.task1,rootProject.tasks.task2,rootProject.tasks.task3,rootProject.tasks.task4
  }
}
This is the code in my root project

Comment: see my answer, i think the problem is that you try to update properties file after it has already been loaded by Gradle .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gradle.properties` file is read once, at the beginning of the build execution, it will not be re-loaded for each sub-project, so if you alter this file from root project tasks, you cannot expect the updated properties to be available for sub-project task. (and I don't think this is a good idea to alter this `gradle.properties` from your build script)

Why don't you simply set your properties using `project.setProperty(key, value)`  ( see [Project DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))) ?

Example:

*root project build:*

```
task setProperties(){
    doLast{
        def var = computeVar()
        project.setProperty('VAR', var )

        // DO NOT DO THAT: 
        //  new File('gradle.properties').append("\nVAR=" + var)
    }
}
```

*from sub-project:*

```
task printProperties(){
    dependsOn tasks.getByPath(':setProperties')
    doLast{
        println "Properties: "
        println "VAR = $VAR"
    }
}
```